# matplotlib - plotting histogram with unique bins

Tags: matplotlib, histogram

I am trying to plot a histogram but the x ticks does not seem to get right.
The plot is intended to get a histogram of frequency counts ( 1 to 13 ) and total rows in 10000.

```
d1 = []
for i in np.arange(1, 10000):
tmp = np.random.randint(1, 13)
d1.append(tmp)
d2 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
d2.hist(width = 0.5)
plt.xticks(np.arange(1, 14, 1))
```

I am trying to plot frequency count of values and not ranges.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to set the bin edges which should be used by the histogram.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d1 = np.random.randint(1, 13, size=1000)
d2 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
bins = np.arange(0,13)+0.5
d2.hist(bins=bins, ec ="k")
plt.xticks(np.arange(1, 13))

plt.show()
```

[image]